# vb.net images with Windows medium font

Tags: vb.net

We have a vb.net desktop application that uses a number of graphical images. All is well when the Windows Display is set to the default small font; however, when the display is set to the medium (125%) font, the graphical images don't display properly. We can accommodate the changes to windows sizes and text boxes, etc using autoscale and autosize; however, this doesn't help with images. Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are asking about the scaling of your application based on DPI settings the user has set.  Just to be sure, can you provide a screenshot of the behavior you are noticing?

Comment: Graphics.DrawImage() already scales for DPI.  What exactly does "don't display properly" mean?

Comment: Screenshot of window with Windows set to default font: !http://www.planguru.com/email-images/smallintro.gif Screenshot with Windows set to larger font: !http://www.planguru.com/email-images/medintro.gif We have tried setting the autoscale property of the forms to font and dpi - neither has an impact on the images. We could set the autoscale to None, but then the user doesn't get the benefit of a larger font in our application.

Answer (score 0):

The controls and maybe the form containing the images are probably changing sizes when the font size changes. Make sure the size of the control containing the image does not change when the font size changes.

Comment: See the screen shots in the previous comments. I would think the size of the control has to change if the overall font size is larger otherwise the windows that mix images and text will not look right.

Answer (score 0):

On the windows form set the following properties:

autosize = true

autoscalemode = dpi